# Регулярное выражение для пароля от 6 символов с использованием цифр, спец. символов, латиницы, наличием строчных и прописных символов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно настроить регулярное выражение для "Сложного пароля": от 6 символов с использованием цифр, спец. символов, латиницы, наличием строчных и прописных символов.
Если введенные символы не соответствуют данному выражению то `return false;`

Comment: Что вы пробовали и что не получилось? Почему это должно быть регулярное выражение?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Необходимо использовать [позитивный просмотр вперёд](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Он позволит обеспечить все перечисленные вами условия.

Вот так выглядит выражение целиком:

```js
/(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*]{6,}/g
```

Вот пример на [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/dT8sD6/1). Можете попробовать написать свои пароли и проверить работу регулярного выражения на соответствие своим требованиям.

Пояснение:

- `(?=.*[0-9])` - строка содержит хотя бы одно число;
- `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])` - строка содержит хотя бы один спецсимвол;
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - строка содержит хотя бы одну латинскую букву в нижнем регистре;
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - строка содержит хотя бы одну латинскую букву в верхнем регистре;
- `[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*]{6,}` - строка состоит не менее, чем из 6 вышеупомянутых символов.

---

Основано на ответе на вопрос:
"[**Javascript regular expression password validation having special characters**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090265/2486051)"

---

## Обновление

Важно понять, что для того, чтобы проверить обязательное наличие определённых символов в строке, достаточно использовать такой шаблон: `(?=.*[%s])`, где вместо `%s` надо указывать требуемый набор символов.

Шаблон должен быть в самом начале регулярного выражения и присутствовать столько раз, сколько уникальных правил для проверки строки вы хотите использовать.

После отрезка с повторениями этого шаблона необходимо использовать обобщённый набор из всех разрешённых символов. Нам надо склеить «куски» в один общий набор разрешённых символов. Затем к нему надо будет применить ограничение по количеству символов, соответствующее выбранной длине строки.

Чтобы в коде легче читалось такое регулярное выражение, и его было легче проверить, в случае опечатки можно использовать такую функцию для генерации итогового выражения:

```
function makePasswordRegExp(patterns, min, max) {
  var min = min || ''; // Если минимальное число символов не указано, берём пустую строку
  var max = max || ''; // Если максимальное число символов не указано, берём пустую строку
  var regex_string = '';
  var rules = [];
  var range = "{" + min + "," + max + "}"; // Разрешённый диапазон для длины строки
  for (rule in patterns) { // Обрабатываем входящий массив из ВСЕХ правил для строки
    if (patterns.hasOwnProperty(rule)) {
      rules.push(patterns[rule]); // Запоминаем правила
      // Формируем последовательность из шаблонов `(?=.*[%s])`
      // Она проверит обязательное присутствие всех символов из входящего набора
      regex_string += "(?=.*[" + patterns[rule] + "])";
    }
  }
  // Добавляем в хвост набор из ВСЕХ разрешённых символов и разрешённую длину строки
  regex_string += "[" + rules.join('') + "]" + range;
  // Собираем всё в одно регулярное выражение
  return new RegExp(regex_string, 'g');
}
```

Использование:

```
// Набор правил
// Имена ключей в этом объекте могут быть любыми
// Они для лучшего понимания частей итогового регулярного выражения
var patterns = {
  'numeric':     '0-9',
  'special':     '!@#$%^&*',
  'latin_lower': 'a-z',
  'latin_upper': 'A-Z'
};

// В вашем случае есть ограничение только по минимальной длине от 6 символов
var min = 6;

// Передаём правила в функцию и смотрим итоговое выражение
console.log(makePasswordRegExp(patterns, min));

// Вывод: /(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9!@#$%^&*a-zA-Z]{6,}/g
```

Безусловно, функцию можно улучшить, добавив в неё проверку большего из двух аргументов `min` и `max` и тому подобное. Она призвана только показать подход, который может упростить отладку таких сложных регулярных выражений.

Comment: регулярка очень хорошая, но сколько нужно опыта чтобы сразу понять что это и где ошибка (если сдедлать опечатку)?) Может обычный цикл эффективнее для этой задачи, что вы думаете?

Comment: @pavel чтобы понять, где ошибка в регулярном выражении, его необходимо разделить на части, как это сделано в пояснениях к нему. Даже с точки зрения читабельности, цикл потребует проверки строки соответствию каждому из условий. То же на то же выйдет. Чтобы проще читалось регулярное выражение, его можно *склеивать* в коде из его ключевых частей в одно целое, а частям присвоить говорящие имена переменных.

Comment: @pavel, дополнил ответ, отвечая на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Не посчитает сложным паролем `Aa% - \0 6dfg`, Вы жестко ограничиваете набор возможных символов и за счет этого теряете кучу знаков вроде запятых, точек и.т.п. Решение проблемы: 1) добавить метасимвол начала строки в начало регулярного выражения 2) разврешить все символы, то есть `.{6,}`, 3) наличие спецсимволов проверять не ограниченным набором символов, а таким `[^\w\s]`

Comment: Шикарное объяснение в апдейте. После прочтения инструкции на первоисточник я мало что понял, но после вашего описания. стало все ясно. Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^\w\s]).{6,}/
```

Очень похоже, на ответ @VenZell, только лишено недостатка, что жестко ограничен набор допустимых символов.
Неправильно требовать от людей "сложный" пароль и при этом ограничивать набор допустимых символов небольшим списком `!@#$%^&*`. Если производить брутфорс такого пароля, то нет ничего слаще - 56 букв, 10 цифр и 8 символов, итого 74 символа. Ну "очень сложно".
Требуя от людей "сложный" пароль имейте ввиду, что они могут захотеть тогда ввести `\0` © ♣ и кучу других символов, которые легко вводятся с помощью `ALT+3333` как в случае символа трефы.

Comment: [^\w\s] лаконичнее заменить на \W