# Валидация поля ввода пароля regex'ом

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Условия:

1. минимум 8 символов
2. минимум одна цифра
3. минимум одна буква латиницы или кириллицы прописная
4. минимум одна буква латиницы или кириллицы заглавная

Мое решение:

```
^(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-ZА-Я])(?=.*[a-zа-я]).*$
```

пропускает

> парольFF

без цифр, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение для пароля от 6 символов с использованием ...цифр, спец. символов, латиницы, наличием строчных и прописных символов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533675/)

Comment: у меня с латиницей вопросов нет, проблема возникает при добавлении кириллицы в выражение

Comment: Посмотрите в ответ на тот вопрос. Вы увидите, что все условия должны быть записаны по отдельности (а не как у вас через или, или отрицание) через просмотр вперед.

Comment: Да, ссылка была полезной и помогла найти верное решение, спасибо!