# Регулярка для поиска нецифрового идентификатора: текст не должен состоять только из цифр

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, django

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярку по таким условиям: текст не должен состоять только из цифр, текст может состоять из цифр, латинских букв обоих регистров, символов подчеркивания и дефиса `_-`.

P.S. Правда, даже примера никакого привести не могу. Знаю как найти цифры `\d`, знаю как найти буквы и символы `[A-Za-z-_]`, но как сделать чтобы строка не могла быть только цифровой не знаю. :(

P.P.S. Возможно будет понятнее если я укажу что я использую регулярку в django-вском `RegexValidator` для валидации поля модели.

Начальным может быть любой из символов, в том числе и число. Это не принципиально. Главное чтобы строка не могла состоять только из чисел.

Comment: Указываете правило на начальные символы, а потом на все остальные [условие1][условие2]+ Примерно так: `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]+`

Comment: Начальные символы? В смысле? Начальным может быть любой из символов, в том числе и число. Это не принципиально. Главное чтобы строка не могла состоять только из чисел.

Comment: В большинсте случаев идентификатор это значение которое начинается не с цифры, у вас другой случай - тогда условие другое.

Comment: Увы. Такая задача. У меня не принимают такое решение когда первый символ не может быть числом.

Comment: Упростите под свой случай http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533675/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82-6-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE

Comment: Спасибо, кажется помогло. Вроде бы вот так работает: (?=.*[A-Za-z\-_])[0-9A-Za-z\-_]

Comment: upd. Обнаружен баг: регулярка пропускает прочие символы если в строке есть буквы латинского алфавита. Например "f*/абвг" - проглотит. А не должна. Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

Comment: @Yalierar в сторону: \d не только ascii цифры ищет. Используйте явно 0-9, если хотите это ограничение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
^(?!\d+$)[\da-zA-Z_-]+$
```

Comment: Хмм, вроде бы тоже работает. А регулярка проще чем та что ниже. :D

Comment: В регулярке выше не используются позиционные проверки, поэтому сложнее.

Comment: Позвольте чуть упростить: `^(?!\d+$)[[:alnum:]_-]+$`

Comment: alnum? Что это? :) Скорее всего это не везде работает, вот например [тут](http://regexr.com/) тестирую - уже не пашет, а [тут](https://regex101.com) работает.

Comment: Это определённый POSIX символьный класс, обозначает ровно то, что я заменил. Обычно если есть поддержка опережающих/ретроспективных проверок, то они и подавно. Плюс (субъективно) читается проще.

Comment: @ValeriyKr alnum не работает для re модуля, а для regex модуля alnum не равнозначен  `\dA-Za-z` (автору нужны только латинские буквы)

Comment: Последнего не учёл, хорошо. Не ориентировался в регулярках никогда на неанглийские локали.

Comment: @ValeriyKr Текст в Питоне обычно представлен в виде Unicode строк (поэтому alnum не только ascii). Локаль тут не имеет значения. Особенно в многопоточном веб-приложении не следует глобальную локаль трогать (автор django использует).

Answer (score 1):

Вашему условию удовлетворяет следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/^[\da-z_-]*([a-z_-]+\d*|\d*[a-z_-]+)[\da-z_-]*$/i
```

`[a-z_-]+\d*|\d*[a-z_-]+` - эта часть обязывает до или после цифры встретиться не цифровому символу из набора разрешенных.

Посмотреть пример работы: https://regex101.com/r/ZyQw18/1

---

**Обновление:** упрощено регулярное выражение

```
/^([a-z_-]+\d*|\d*[a-z_-]+)+$/i
```

Посмотреть пример работы: https://regex101.com/r/ZyQw18/4

---

**Обновление 2:** решение работает еще быстрее

```
/^[\da-z_-]*[a-z_-][\da-z_-]*$/i
```

Посмотреть пример работы: https://regex101.com/r/ZyQw18/2

Comment: Кажется работает, спасибо!

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение можно упростить, потому что задачу можно переформулировать так: «в строке должен быть минимум один НЕ цифренный литерал». А если просто посмотреть на регулярное выражение, то в первой альтернативе `\d*` входит в `[\da-z_-]*$`, во второй альтернативе аналогично.

Comment: @ReinRaus, я упростил регулярное выражение

Comment: Можно еще немного проще: https://regex101.com/r/ZyQw18/2

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасибо, добавил в ответ со ссылкой на вас

Comment: Спасибо, но можно и без меня, мне не обидно, а ответ будет чище и без отсылок.