# поиск всех вхождений в диапазоне

Tags: регулярные-выражения

есть такая регулярка:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$
```

она находит и строку "QWE", и строку "QWEasd", и строку "QWEasd123".

то есть она находит любое вхождение, а возможно сделать в рамках одного поиска что бы она искала все сразу? (т.е. находила только "QWEasd123")

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение для пароля от 6 символов с использованием цифр, спец. символов, латиницы, наличием строчных и прописных символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533675/186083)

Comment: мой скилл поиска не так хорош как ваш. в целом это подходит, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

> *находила только "QWEasd123"*

Вариант на PHP:

```
$str = 'QWEasd123'; // true
$str = 'QWEasd';   // false
$str = 'QWE';     // false

$bool = (bool) preg_match('~^(\pL)?(?(1)\pL*\d+\pL*)$~i', $str);

var_dump($bool);
```