# Регулярные выражения. Проверка сложности пароля

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Учебное задание:

> Написать функцию, которая использует регулярные выражения для проверки того, что переданная строка представляет собой сильный пароль. Сильными считаются пароли, которые состоят по крайней мере из восьми символов, содержат символы в верхнем и нижнем регистрах и включают по крайней мере одну цифру.

Выполнил все условия кроме выборке пароля по длине:

```
[A-Z]+[a-z]+\w{1,}
```

[Пример на Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pn0Iu9/1)

Что нужно прописать, чтобы добавить условие выборки по длине пароля (не меньше 8 символов)?

Comment: Не все. Проверьте, например, пароль ``absghk4D``

Comment: У вас в вопросе нет вопроса ..

Comment: Мне казалось и так понятно, ну хорошо, добавил сам вопрос: "Что нужно прописать, чтобы добавить условие выборки по длине пароля (не меньше 8 символов)?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Взял и немного упростил регулярку из этого [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533681/201445):

```
import re
pattern_password = re.compile(r'^(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.*[a-z].*)(?=.*[A-Z].*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$')

print(bool(pattern_password.match('absghk4D')))  # True
print(bool(pattern_password.match('abc123FF')))  # True
print(bool(pattern_password.match('123ABCac')))  # True
print(bool(pattern_password.match('abcFF123')))  # True
print()
print(bool(pattern_password.match('absghk4D $%#$')))  # False
print(bool(pattern_password.match('')))               # False
print(bool(pattern_password.match('bsghk4D')))        # False
print(bool(pattern_password.match('abc_aaFF')))       # False
print(bool(pattern_password.match('abcabcac')))       # False
print(bool(pattern_password.match('ABCDF!@##')))      # False
```

Пояснение регулярки:

- `(?=.*[0-9])` - строка содержит хотя бы одно число;
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - строка содержит хотя бы одну латинскую букву в нижнем регистре;
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - строка содержит хотя бы одну латинскую букву в верхнем регистре;
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}` - строка состоит не менее, чем из 8 вышеупомянутых символов.

---

Чтобы добавить поддержку спецсимволов нужно в последнюю часть регулярки их включить:

```
...[0-9a-zA-Z$%#^]{8,}$')
```

Тогда и

```
print(bool(pattern_password.match('$b#FF123')))  # True
```

Comment: Разве [`abs-ghk4D $%#$`](https://ideone.com/sq9q0W) не сильный пароль?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, в условии задачи есть перечень символов в пароле, и туда не входят спецсимволы

Comment: Нет там такого требования. А если и так, тогда почему у вас валидно [`absghk4D $%#$`](https://ideone.com/phBWdB)? Что-то тут не так.

Comment: @Ronin Если неправильно проводить валидацию, то можно получить неправильный результ.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, спасибо за замечание, подправил регулярку

Comment: Про спецсимволы: поскольку они явно не запрещены, то на мой взгляд, могут присутствовать в пароле. Не сказано, что приведенный список допустимых символов - исчерпывающий. Он просто минимальный.

Comment: @Эникейщик, хорошо, фраза в вопросе "...по крайней мере..." позволяет думать что могут быть и спец символы. Ответ расширил

Comment: @gil9red с новой регуляркой не проходит выборку "Qwertyu8", хотя он удовлетворяет условиям задачи.

Comment: @Ronin, у меня проходит: `print(bool(pattern_password.match('Qwertyu8')))  # True`

Comment: Я верю коду и тот пароль проверил в коде перед тем как вам написать. А по той ссылке у вас не 'Qwertyu8', а 'Qwertyu8 '. Да и ссылку вы не ту указали :) она ведет на v1, а у вас v3 :)

Comment: @gil9red import re
pattern_password = re.compile(r'^(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.*[a-z].*)(?=.*[A-Z].*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$')
mo = pattern_password.findall('Qwertyui870, qwertyui, Qwertyui, Qwertyu8, fdffdfddf, ddddddd8, DDDDDDD8, Qq8, Qw546754, 32432435, absghk4D')
print(mo) Извиняюсь за неказистый вид кода (никак не получается в комментариях оформить его правильно), но если это ввести в IDLE - интерперетатор вообще молчит. За основу взял вашу регулярку.

Comment: @Ronin, так не работает. Моя регулярка работает с целым паролем, проверяя все строку от начала и до конца, поэтому любой лишний символ провалит проверку, а у вас строка с паролями разделенными запятыми, что будет противоречить регулярке и условию задачи Т.е. вам нужно будет сначала разделить строку, а после проверить каждый из них: `mo = [password for password in passwords_text.split(', ') if bool(pattern_password.match(password))]` попробуйте так

Comment: @gil9red Да, все правильно. Не обратил внимание на условие, что должна проверяться лишь переданная строка. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

def test_pwd(pwd):
    '''
    >>> test_pwd("absghk4D")
    True
    >>> test_pwd("absg4D")
    False
    >>> test_pwd("'\ra\/bsghk4D")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
    '''
    def f(exp, word=pwd):
        return bool(re.search(exp, word))
    return f('\d') and f('[A-Z]') and f('[a-z]') and f('[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}')
```

Можно также обработать исключения, которые могут возникнуть из-за введённого пользователем варианта.

Comment: `\w` включает в себя еще и `_`

Comment: Где тут ответ? Здесь просто выписка из документации.

Comment: поправил чтоб стало ответом

Comment: добавил чтобы работало с `"absghk4D"`

Comment: @EugeneDennis, мне кажется что можно вместо findall использовать search, и сразу возвращать bool: `return bool(re.search(...))`. ` r'{}'.format(pwd)` выглядит странно, почему просто не `pwd`? Еще в `def f(exp, word=pwd):` есть `exp`, но оно не используется

Comment: поправил, спасибо

Comment: Еще, `def f(exp, word=pwd)` -> `def f(exp)` и внутри: `return bool(re.search(exp, pwd))`. raw-строки тут не помогут, хоть там и используется форматирование. Да и питоничий re умный и может работать и с \d и c \\d

Comment: стараюсь в функциях использовать только переменные аргументы

Comment: А вы и будете использовать аргумент, но функции выше. Да и `(r'{}'.format(exp)` не нужно, просто оставьте там переменную `exp`. Это будет работать